# Displaying a String of a java class in an activity widget

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that consist of an activity and a java class that extends AsyncTask. So I have a String in the java class that called **resFromServer** 
which I want to display it in a message in a suitable android widget like Alertdialog .

I want someone to help me in how to access that String from the activity

```
public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {

    String url = "http://192.168.1.8:89/Derdeery/b.php";



    protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
        JSONObject json = data[0];

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build());
        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json="+json.toString());

            post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            post.setEntity(se);

            HttpResponse response;
            response = client.execute(post);
            String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


               Log.i("Response from server", **resFromServer**);


        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        { e.printStackTrace();}

        return jsonResponse;
    }

}
```

the activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        } }
```

Answer (score 2):

Proper solution: create an `instance` of the `AsyncTask` and make a callback in order to catch the response into any `Activity`. All Activities which will implement this interface, can retrieve the result of the AsyncTask. This is more flexible and can be used by multiple Activities with just one single AsyncTask.

You have to create the instance and return the `String` response, in `AsyncTask`:

```
public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, String> {
    private AsyncCallback asyncCallback; // callback variable

    // constructor
    public JSONTransmitter(Context context) {
        // attach the callback to any context
        asyncCallback = (AsyncCallback) context;
    }

    // create the interface
    public static interface AsyncCallback {
        void onResponse(String res);
    }

    ...
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (asyncCallback != null) {
            // call the onResponse method for callback
            asyncCallback.onResponse(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can implement to any `Activity` the callback by setting its `Context` as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements JSONTransmitter.AsyncCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // set the Context to the AsyncTask when you create it
        // in order to return here and execute the request
        new JSONTransmitter(this).execute(...);
    } 

    ...
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String res) {
        // handle the string response when it's called from onPostExecute()
        Log.v("From_MainActivity", "AsyncTask returns this: "+res);
    }
}
```

Therefore, you can do what you want in the `Activity` with `resFromServer` (result string) from `AsyncTask` class.

Comment: I get this error AsyncCallback cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I haven't any error, @JavaFan. I just had to change the return `String` by a `JSONObject` because of your AsyncTask type (`AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject>`), otherwise I can run the script. Do you use Eclispe?

Comment: Is there a class called AsyncCallback ?  I use Eclipse

Comment: `AsyncCallback` is not a class, it's an interface from `JSONTransmitter`. Check your import, it's often the issue. If not, Clean and Rebuild (Eclispe can have some problem to regenerate the classes).

Comment: I get error here :  super.onPostExecute(result);                                      the method onPostExecute(JSONObject) in the type AsyncTask<JSONObject,JSONObject,JSONObject> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: That's why I said for *I just had to change the return String by a JSONObject* previously. You want to return a string or a jsonobject? Your asynctask wants a jsonobject because it's declared as `AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject>` but if you want to return a string, just change this: `... extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, String>` and don't forget to return a string in `doInBackground();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100657/discussion-between-javafan-and-fllo).

Answer (score 0):

Pass your activity as **parameter** to your `AsyncTask` class constructor :

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

    Activity mActivity;

    public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
       mActivity = ativity;
    }
```

Then update your activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         int id = mActivity.findViewById(...);
  }
```

You should not use the `doInBackground` method to update the activity. 
Use the `onPostExecute` because it uses the main Thread.